# Could the Off Topic close reasons screen get a bit of McLovin'?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, close-dialog

As everyone is becoming aware, the [close reasons have been reworked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns).

When voting to close a question, the first dialog is nicely laid out and easy to look at:

[image]

But the dialog containing the off-topic reasons is considerably harder to read and assimilate due to its layout and the fonts/weighting used. It's almost a wall of text:

[image]

When you've changed things, you want to make it easy for people to follow the new process. You don't want them to struggle to work out what the appropriate reason should be.

Can we have this re-jiggered to match the style used in the first close dialog?

Comment: More than 5 radio buttons without being grouped is not visually clear any more.

Answer (score 8):

We have enough room on that dialog to do this (of course, with better formatting and well thought-out titles):

[image]

which would mitigate most of the negative effects of the change.

Comment: This is nice, but there's no room left to expand "other".

Comment: @Yannis `dialog.height += otherField.height;` :)