# Closing a question (Off topic) dialog

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, design

When closing a question I am presented with this dialog:

[image]

Which is nicely laid out and clear what options are available to me (As to why the question should be closed).

However when I choose `Off Topic`.  I get this dialog which IMO appears cluttered and a bit too full on, making it harder to chose the correct option.

[image]

In a future release would it be possible to maybe have a bit more of padding between the options or colour contrast (Black and grey) or a heading, like in the first dialog.

For example:

**General Computing Hardware/Software**

```
   .... specific content
```

**Does not demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**

```
   .... specific content
```

I think this would make it slightly easier on the eye and make the options stand out.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185901/164376

Comment: @joran - thanks, I did look for this before I posted.

Comment: I just happened to remember it, that's all. Can't believe you didn't think to search fo "McLovin", though. ;)

Comment: @joran - haha :)