# Make it clearer that some of the close / on-hold reasons have additional options

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, on-hold

It's not that clear that the Off Topic option has some additional choices after it. I suggest that by adding an ellipsis to the end of the Off Topic wording (and probably the Duplicate one too for consistency sake) it should make it clearer that, by selecting that option, you'll be given more options to choose.

Here's my beautiful mockup to illustrate this.

> [image]

Comment: Seems like an easy change for significant user benefit.

Comment: I'm not opposed, but why would you need to know that?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Because http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186024/can-we-rename-the-off-topic-close-reason-label-on-the-primary-screen

Comment: Well, for one thing the Migrate option has now been hidden further down the hierarchy so it currently looks like it's not an option anymore.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek, where the move to meta option is, for example.

Comment: How do you migrate now?

Comment: @LanceRoberts There's an option inside Off Topic called *"This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"*.

Comment: While I'm not opposed to this idea, it's worth mentioning that part of this is just the transition from one system to another; after the short transition time it's unlikely to be as much of an issue.

Comment: @JonW, hmmm, I don't see that option, maybe they require a certain rep level (I'm just shy of 10k).

Comment: @LanceRoberts You won't see it here on meta.  It'll be there for you on SO.

Comment: @Servy, I tested on SO, only saw options that linked to the about page on SuperUser and ServerFault, no migration dialog, or wording that JonW stated was there.

Comment: @Servy not exactly true - as people achieve more reputation the close dialog will become available to them, so there is still going to be a learning curve needed here. if we can reduce that learning curve that should help with correct closure reasons being chosen in future by newly rep'ed users.

Comment: OK, tried again and saw the option, thanks.

Comment: @JonW The issue now is that many of the questions that meet the criteria for several of those sub-reasons aren't closed as off topic.  They're closed as TL or NARQ.  After a little while someone who just dings 3k will have been used to seeing other questions meeting those criteria closed by others as OT with a particular close reason, even if they haven't been closing them personally with that reason.

Answer (score 11):

It now looks like this:

[image]

Comment: "minimal understanding of problem" (under "off topic because..") should be changed to "minimal understanding/effort shown."  Often they obviously understand the problem, but have put no effort into even attempting to solve it themselves *(doubly true for homework problems)*.  Or possibly those should be two separate choices.

Comment: @BlueRaja that should probably be a separate question / feature request, since it's not really related to this change.

Answer (score 8):

This would be a good idea since looking at the off-topic reason doesn't let you know that you will have a custom option, or any option at all.  It's especially important since the off-topic reason is being used for so much now, not all of which would be intuitively off-topic.