# Some custom off-topic close reasons don't really describe off-topic questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, close-reasons, off-topic, custom-close-reasons

These two off-topic close reasons don't seem like they describe off-topic questions.

> - Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it. See SSCCE.org for guidance.
> - Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Both of them sound like that the question was on-topic, but lacking some crucial piece of information. Specifically if a question is "concerning problems with code you've written" it sounds more like it's *exactly* on-topic.

Compared to other standard close reasons, I don't see why the above close reasons describe off-topic questions any more than these:

> - **unclear what you're asking**
>     Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
> - **too broad**
>     There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Is the off-topic list used for site-specific close reasons only because it's the only list that can be customized, whether or not the close reason actually describes an off-topic question? Wouldn't it be clearer if the main list could be customized and these close reasons put there?

Comment: Closely related: [Can we rename the off topic close reason label on the primary screen?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186024)

Comment: I cant find it now, but I did see an asker being mad because his question was being closed as off-topic when the reason really was that he didn't include code to reproduce his problem.

Comment: It seems the close reason has finally been renamed to "A community-specific reason", nearly 7 years later. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New UI for modifying community-specific close reasons (for moderators) – bugs, feature requests, etc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346834/282094) or old but closer duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215567/282094

Answer (score 4):

That's a pretty good observation...

See, until very recently there were a couple of other close reasons available:

> #### Not a real question
>
> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.
>
> #### Too Localized
>
> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

These covered a *lot* of ground. So much so that it was often difficult to tell why they were being used - or if they were being misused. So the former was split into "Unclear" and "Too Broad", while the latter was dropped entirely...

But that left some gaps, some common problems that weren't being addressed: questions that just dumped a huge amount of broken code (or linked to it off-site), and questions that demand a working solution to some problem without clearly defining either the problem itself or the nature of that solution. These two Off Topic sub-reasons are our attempt at tackling them directly; they could *probably* be shoehorned into "Unclear", but this puts us in a position of having very little clear guidance on what *specifically* is needed to clarify the question.

Comment: Instead of custom off topic reasons , why not have sub reasons for unclear? Put the two reasons the OP mentions into sub reasons for 'unclear'?

Comment: They're not a perfect subset of Unclear either, and frankly I find the extra submenu too annoying to want it for more close reasons. Renaming Off Topic probably makes more sense.

Comment: +1 for 'Renaming Off Topic'. I like that idea. 'Out of scope'? 'not appropriate'?