# Where is the "minimal understanding" reason?

Tags: support, close-reasons

I wanted to flag a question as "minimal understanding", but this close reason is replaced by:

> This question was caused by a problem that can't be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was solved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

But this close reason doesn't fit for questions with a "minimal understanding of the problem". So how should I flag these questions?

Comment: Yeah, there is ongoing discussion regarding this. The opinion seems to be that many of these woukd fit under too broad or unclear and the rest are fine

Comment: This is another good post: [Close Vote options no longer include option for “must include code” and “must show minimal understanding”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215567/close-vote-options-no-longer-include-option-for-must-include-code-and-must-sh), which is a duplicate but points to the question and answer that mostly prompted this change.

Comment: @RichardTingle Sometimes the question is very focused and well-written but simply shows zero effort on the asker's part. Is this really what we want SO to become? *Hey do my work for me kthx*

Comment: @Yuck You will note that I wrote the duplicate, so I am at least torn. However, if its a question thats going to be of use to a large number of people, then I can see the value of it being answered

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411706/sql-max-min-avg-salary Here's a good example that is not too broad nor is it unclear. It does not, however, demonstrate a minimal understanding. What I lack now is a good way to communicate that. VTC for whatever now I guess.