# Should the "demonstrate minimal understanding" close reason be promoted to first tier of close reasons?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

It seems that the <kbd>off-topic</kbd> → <kbd>demonstrate minimal understanding question</kbd> close reason is one of the most used close reasons one consistently sees.  Is there a reason that this should not be on the first screen of reasons? This would:

1. Not necessarily have the question categorized as off-topic, as the question could be perfectly on-topic, just lacking any research effort or examples of current efforts made to solve a problem. Having the item be noted as off-topic is a bit misleading.
2. Give higher visibility to the need for voters to enforce this basic tenet of how Stack Overflow should work.
3. Require less clicks to get to this highly used item.

Comment: I believe those "second tier" close reasons are site specific close reasons; "minimal understanding" is specific to stack overflow

Comment: Having just pretended to flag just to see for myself; it appears that the "demonstrate minimal understanding" one *is* specific to Stack Overflow.

Comment: OK. But since Stackoverflow is the flagship site in the network and since this particular code criteria is key in helping to enforce that questions are focused, perhaps an exception to this default approach should be considered?

Comment: If an exception is made though, where does the line get drawn?

Comment: They are just tried to make it hard to pick that reason.  That's not working, even the most gawdawful question can merit two clicks.  We do care.

Comment: @DennisMeng What line needs to be drawn? I honestly don't see why there needs to be some differentiation between general close reasons and site-specific close reasons, especially when the site-specific close reasons might be more frequently used and thus should have more visibility from an end user standpoint.

Comment: I guess my concern is along the same lines as those expressed here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186024/can-we-rename-the-off-topic-close-reason-label-on-the-primary-screen?rq=1 - but I would go a step further in saying that I don't see any reason for there to be two selections levels, especially for the most frequently used close reasons on a specific site.  Certainly it is not a huge technical challenege to intermingle general close reasons and site-specific ones in a single dialog, giving better visibility to those reasons most important to the specific site.

Comment: I'm simply concerned that promoting it to first tier might make it become more abused/overused in cases where another close reason, editing or a comment would be appropriate - otherwise I don't see why not (apart from making the flagging panel **even bigger :O**).

Comment: "Having the item be noted as off-topic is a bit misleading." -- good look trying to argue that position. There are half a dozen questions on meta and at least a dozen answers addressing this, and massive community support for it, but no go. And +1, BTW, I completely agree with this suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

It should definitely not be promoted to the first tier of reasons. If it was you risk it becoming the new NARQ or NC, both of which got used extensively and were just the easy cop-out reason to pick when you didn't particularly like a question. (Slight problems with the way the question is phrased? Pick *Not A Real Question*. Don't care for what the question is asking or where it's going? Choose *Not Constructive*. BOOM. Question closed.)

Another reason to ponder: you risk it becoming an elitest close reason that will be used to nuke questions from newbies who don't quite know how to phrase their question or include the right information. If that reason is promoted to the top tier then I would predict an explosion of questions on Meta from new users complaining about their questions being closed.

Comment: I agree that this is a potential problem.  Perhaps if "on hold" is to be used as intended, perhaps another "on hold" option indicating that the question should be on hold pending further explanation/detail/examples should be considered.