# "This question doesn't meet a <SITE> guideline" is incorrect if site name begins with a vowel sound

Tags: feature-request, review, grammar

I was reviewing close votes on Ask Ubuntu, and noticed a grammatical error in the reasoning message:

[image: This question doesn't meet a Ask Ubuntu guideline]

Currently, it says:

> This question doesn't meet **a** Ask Ubuntu guideline

It should say:

> This question doesn't meet **an** Ask Ubuntu guideline

I'm posting this here since there are other SE sites with names that begin with a vowel sound (e.g. Interpersonal Skills and Esperanto).

I know this is probably a bit of a fiddly bug, and it's not really that major, but, if possible, it should probably be fixed.

Alternatively, changing the sentence to avoid the problem completely could work:

> This question doesn't meet a guideline on Ask Ubuntu

Comment: “This question doesn't meet one of <SITE> guideline”?

Comment: @Braiam that should be "one of <SITE> guidelines," plural.

Comment: Your question currently says, "This question doesn't meet a Ask Ubuntu guideline" twice. You don't actually need the alt text since you've transcribed the screenshot. Also, the lack of punctuation in the alt text creates a run-on sentence for screen readers.

Comment: Though watch out for "Unix and Linux," "User Experience," and "Ukrainian Language."

Comment: Two years and five months have passed, and this is still an embarrassing situation&mdash;even more so on the [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) Stack Exchange sites, where we are presumed to be explaining and demonstrating proper grammar to those who seek to learn.

Comment: Three and an half more years of a embarrassing and an seemingly easily fixed problem. Is an solution hard to implement? Can't a individual string just be adjusted (perhaps even by an moderator)?

Comment: @Joachim Just FYI: to get this on SE's radar, a [tag:status-review] tag needs be added to the question. A bounty brings more attention from regular users, which is helpful when the issue needs more support or input from users, but doesn't bring it to the attention of Stack Overflow staff. Adding the [tag:status-review] tag generates a ticket in SE's task system, which will be triaged into an actual feature request/bug sent to developers. To have a [tag:status-review] tag added to the question, the normal process is to raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag to request it be added.

Comment: @TheWanderer Pity I can't give bounties to the question themselves :|

Answer (score 12):

Another solution (credit to @EddieKal):

> **Not suitable for this site**.  This question does not meet [site-name] guidelines.

This would work for all the sites, and be far easier than fixing each grammar error on each site with this problem.

This has also been reported over at [Grammar error in review:  Does this affect several SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354233/grammar-error-in-review-does-this-affect-several-se-sites), although it is not just the review that is affected, it also affects "Needs Improvement" in the flag list on sites with names that begin with vowel sounds, like [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/):

[image]

> "Does not meet one or more"

would also work (credit to @JourneymanGeek).

Comment: Personally, I don't like this one. "Doesn't meet *a* guideline" is much more precise than "Doesn't meet guidelines". In particular, it correctly indicates that someone has actually identified a specific guideline which the question fails to meet. The alternative sounds a bit like weasel words, like "for security purposes".

Comment: "does not meet one or more" might sort out the potential pluralisation bug

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica ...which got deleted.

Comment: Yes. It was explained to me that what I *should* have done if I wanted to bring attention to this question (and your answer) is to "bump" it with a suitable edit. My own follow-up question got closed as a dupe of this one and was racking up DVs, so it was better for it to be deleted.

Comment: Any progress yet?