# Grammar error in review: does this affect several SE sites?

Tags: bug, review, grammar

A dedicated ELL contributor has just brought a grammar issue in a review queue prompt to our attention (thank you Davo!). [Grammar error in Review](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/grammar-error-in-review)

[image]

Apparently the reason description under the "Not suitable for this site" close category contains an error: "a" precedes a word starting with a vowel where "an" should be used. I am not sure this is something that affects other sites whose names also start with vowels--it would appear so--but it has been spotted on ELL where I am a moderator. This issue doesn't seem fixable within the scope of tools made available to mods. How do we fix this?

**Possible solution**: Shall we just change the description to "This question doesn't meet [site name] guidelines"?

Comment: Yes, I think it does.  See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbJOH.png) screenshot from AskUbuntu.  It should say *an* AskUbuntu guideline.

Comment: I like your possible solution.

Comment: Same situation at ELU, too.

Comment: It isn't just the review - it's also the flag list, under Needs Improvement --> Doesn't meet a AskUbuntu guideline.  Changing it to "doesn't meet [site-name] guidelines" would be a much better grammatical solution than just "a" for all sites.

Comment: This is already reported: ["This question doesn't meet a <SITE> guideline" is incorrect if site name begins with a vowel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349877/this-question-doesnt-meet-a-site-guideline-is-incorrect-if-site-name-begins)

Comment: Eddie, I changed the [tag:support] to [tag:bug], as it *is* a grammatical bug.  [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349877/this-question-doesnt-meet-a-site-guideline-is-incorrect-if-site-name-begins) post is also tagged with [tag:bug], if you seek validation.

Comment: @Ollie Yeah that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Related: *[Pluralization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times)* *[bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791)*

Comment: Still a bug in April 2021.

Comment: @Davo Apparently not the company's priority.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it looks like it does affect the other sites - see this screenshot from [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/):

[image]

I also agree with your possible solution of changing it to:

> "This question doesn't meet [site name] guidelines"

It would be way easier than correcting all the grammar errors for each site with this issue, easier than switching from "a" to "an".  It would be a much better grammatical solution than just "a".

Comment: There probably only is one string in the Razor view *This question doesn't meet a @(SiteName) guidelines*.  They can't correct all the grammar errors for each site. Your proposed solution is most likely the only option.

Comment: Imagine changing 174 grammar errors in each site... _shudders_

Comment: @10Repisn'tactiveonMSE I don't want to ;).  That would be nuts.

Comment: I actually prefer the proposed solution but why is it the only option? All is needed is checking whether or not _@(SiteName)_ starts with a vowel to decide whether to use _a_ or _an_. Am I missing something?

Comment: @41686d6564 don't forget that there are also non-english sites  that run on the same code base. You don't want to add too much logic that only makes sense for English sites. If a one fix suits all exists it is preferred I guess.

Comment: @41686d6564 It doesn't work for all vowels. For example, you wouldn't say "an Unix & Linux" because the initial sound is not a vowel. I don't have data as to whether making an exception for u would be sufficient among the sites in the network, but it certainly doesn't work for all words starting with u because some of those actually start with a vowel sound. In any case, it's not worth it, because another site could come along that has an exception.