# How can I close a question on a language site that is written in that language, but off-topic?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, off-topic

I want to close a question on *[French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/)* that is absolutely not about the French language at all; it's just a random question in French. When I press "Close", the only options I have are:

- Duplicate
- A community-specific reason
- Needs details or clarity
- Needs more focus
- Opinion-based

None of these fit. They already assume the question is on-topic. When I choose community-specific, I get:

- <two community-specific reasons>
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network (not what I want to pick, I don't think there's a site about this)
- Other - add a comment

Do I have to pick "other" just to choose Off-Topic? It seems so weird. I see many questions (like [this one](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12945/signification-du-doigt-dhonneur-dans-les-pays-francophones)) closed as off-topic with no other reason given and no comment about it. It's just out of the scope of this SE site.

How do I pick this closing reason?

Comment: I have filed a feature request asking that the words "off-topic" be added to the community-specific reason option so it's clearer to others that they're meant to use that option: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346436/377214

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog Yep, definitely the problem I'm facing. I just upvoted since I don't want to add a hundredth comment, I'm not sure how I can support more than that. It's sad that this is a known issue for 2+ years...

Answer (score 11):

> Do I have to pick "other" just to choose Off-Topic?

Yes. Low-reputation users like me have the option to flag as "Blatantly off-topic":

[image]

but since you can cast actual close *votes*, that option is not available to you. Some sites still have the default close reason

> This question does not appear to be about [insert site topic here] within the scope defined in the help center.

but the close reasons on French.SE have been made more specific. You'll have to write a comment, and you could take advantage of this by directing them to the right Stack Exchange site and explain they'd have to ask in English. (Though in this particular case I don't know the right site.) If you're feeling lazy, you can even type "because it's off-topic" and delete the generated comment.

The question you linked to has been closed a long time ago; closing has seen a couple of evolutions since then. It's not 100% representative for the current process.

Comment: Ok, what I did is choose "Other", type "because it's not about french language" but I left the comment. By "the close reasons on French.SE have been made more specific", should I understand that "Off-topic" is the default community-specific reason until more are added? Shouldn't "off-topic" still be one of the reason?

Comment: *Shouldn't "off-topic" still be one of the reason?* - well, it doesn't really help users much in making their question on-topic. Which close reasons are (to be) used is a discussion you should raise on [French Meta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You might consider supporting my feature request: [Please reinstate the words "off-topic" into the closing dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346436/377214)