# Appropriate custom close reason for unanswered questions about deprecated server API

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, obsolete-information, no-answers

Within Facebook API, the REST API has been deprecated. Previously it was possible to clear out the unanswered list by closing these questions as "too localized". With the new close options, I am unsure how to approach this. What would be an appropriate message to state that the question at its current date is unanswerable due to functions that no longer work?

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about obsolete API functionality?

Comment: Is that really a good reason to close a question?

Comment: @Joe well that's why I'm asking... or should I just be leaving hundreds of dead questions that will never be able to be answered again

Comment: That was my question :)  I could see that going both ways.

Comment: what about "unclear" as in "what's that google reader thing you're talking about?"

Comment: @JanDvorak Oh god no.  I don't think _damnatio memoriae_ is a good policy for StackOverflow.

Comment: Good use case for "Obsolete" http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185120/147247 - closers could refrain from using it if there were good answers on the question

Comment: @JimDagg not even for popular technology that was phased out without official replacement nevertheless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of the preset options could be pressed into this service:

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it.

Even if code is present, it will no longer be sufficient to reproduce the problem. Another possibility is:

> unclear what you're asking

This is a little more far-fetched, but as in Jan Dvorak's [example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188635/appropriate-custom-close-reason-for-unanswered-questions-about-deprecated-server#comment581240_188635), "*what's that Google Reader thing you're talking about?*"

If those options are a bit of a stretch, perhaps we can draw on some of the terminology from the Help Center. The [on-topic list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) includes these two items:

> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

To convert those guidelines into a close reason, perhaps variations on the following would work:

> ...appears to be off-topic because it is not commonly used by programmers
>
> ...appears to be off-topic because it does not contain a practical, answerable problem.

And finally, the close reason you posted:

> ...appears to be off-topic because it is about obsolete API functionality

certainly seems to be usable. It focuses on the *what* rather than the *why*, which is probably okay.

It is possible to combine the two approaches at the risk of becoming overly wordy:

> ...appears to be off-topic because it is about obsolete API functionality which is not commonly used by programmers